# Does Myspace offer an RSS/iCalendar or export for events?

Tags: rss, myspace

Does Myspace offer an RSS export of the events page? I'd like to synchronize with http://events.myspace.com/5570864/Events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, other people, annoyed by the same thing, have created a third-party solution:

http://makedatamakesense.com/myspace/event/

And, then you have to give the non-event URL: http://www.myspace.com/5570864

I am not sure how often they re-crawl and update. If anyone knows of a more official solution feel free to answer. I know they have a hidden official RSS feed for users.